# Kony - How to restart a memcached server

Tags: memcached, temenos-quantum

I am new to kony, Does anyone know how to restart the memcached server and location of start and stop files ? please help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you server running in Linux server use following comment 
%KMAP_SERVER_HOME%\memcached\memcached -p 21201 

if your server in windows 
double click %KMAP_SERVER_HOME%\memcached\memcached.exe 

Please make sure that your middle ware is memcache enabled. 

to check your memcache status use following Linux comment 
echo status | nc  21201